# What to do if comment is misinterpreted

Tags: discussion

My question comes in flow of this closed question :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402111/how-do-i-read-stdinput-and-write-stdouput?noredirect=1#comment39622836_25402111

I had posted a comment, which OP felt was rude, I didn't meant it that way. Apparently when the OP commented about it and existing user flagged it, I realized my mistake and deleted it.

**My Question**

What to do in such cases when comments are interpreted in way it were not meant?

I have apologized and deleted my comment but OP seems to get bad impression!

Comment: I don't quite see the issue here. You apologized for your comment, removed it, and the original questioner accepted your apologies. End of story to me, what more would you want to happen?

Comment: Note that the entire discussion so far could be removed any time, now the question has been edited and nominated for re-opening.

Comment: @Jongware : can you please vote it to reopen?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi : *issue* is not about how OP behaved, issue was how *I* should go ahead in such cases....deleting comments is one thing obviously but is there any other thing that could/should have been done?

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed. This seems to be a reasonable question about communication and etiquette on Stack Overflow. Why is this off-topic?

Comment: @Fish, I can only speak for myself, but I voted to close as "can no longer be reproduced / obsolete" for the reasons stated in my first comment. Other users have chosen another close reason, but I cannot say why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What to do in such cases when comments are interpreted in way it were not meant?

Whether you see the other side immediately after hitting "submit", or whether you find out via feedback from the intended target, it is always appropriate to **delete** the comment. Just hover over it and click the little gray "x" button.

There is no cost to deleting comments. It won't cause you to come any nearer to a posting ban. The only silliness is that deleting a comment counts as a *vote* on a comment, so you won't be able to delete multiple comments in rapid succession or delete a comment and cast a vote on another comment during this narrow window of time (I think it's like 5 seconds).

> I have apologized and deleted my comment but OP seems to get bad impression!!

Then you've already done more than you are required to do. If someone misinterpreted something you said, then apologizing is always appropriate. It is customary in any type of interaction and shows that you are humble enough to admit your own error in judgment.

If the apology doesn't seem to satisfy the other person, then there is not much else you can do. You just have to assume that they are otherwise having a bad day—perhaps they're debugging a very frustrating programming problem?—and that they will get over it eventually.

Besides, if you've deleted the comment, you've obliterated all the evidence<sup>1</sup>. So now if they're all acting the fool, no one else will know what their problem is. :-)

Above all, we must all be mindful to keep in mind that this is [The Internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdoyt.png). That means not having such a thin skin that stuff random people type can offend you. And it also means being extra careful about the things that you type, because emotion is difficult to convey.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Mostly true. Moderators can still see deleted comments, but regular users (not even 10k+ users) cannot.</sup>